# Creating an array from a number of array objects.

Tags: java, arrays

cant find it anywhere but what I would like to do is write a function that finds every 5 strings in an array from a text file and converts them 8 to a string. and does this until there are no more strings left in the text file.

OR

use split to split the lines but also use split to split up them lines for example I would like:

```
name;type;body;due
lewis;homework;blahblahblah;12/12/12
```

converted into:
    Array[name, type, body, due];
    Array[lewis, homework, blahblahblah, 12/12/12];

thank you :) if I haven't explained well ask me and I will try my best to explain better :)

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question?

Comment: I want to create multiple Strings from a bufferedreader input per line. create an array from those strings by seperating them using split(";") into an array.

Comment: Aren't you done after the `split(";")`?

Comment: @LewisYouldon do you have a *specific* issue?

Comment: What I mean is user split to make the strings from the lines. and split the splitted lines again. but hold each one in a different array so I can easily call each value to a JLabel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I followed you correctly. Just putting this forward.

for each line 
String [] strArr = lineStr.split(";");

Comment: its hard to explain what i mean sorry. what I want to do is split the lines up into SEPERATE strings (not in an array) and then split them strings up into seperate arrays

Comment: @LewisYouldon, The array contains the separated strings...this answer meets your requirements.

Comment: thank you  :) was having a bit of a stupid moment sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What about this ?

```
public static String[][] toArrays(String text, String sep1, String sep2) {
    String[] lines = text.split(sep1);
    if (lines == null) {
        return null;
    }

    String[][] arrays = new String[lines.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String[] words = lines[i].split(sep2);
        arrays[i] = words;
    }

    return arrays;
}
```

And you call it with :

```
    String[][] s = toArrays("name;type;body;due\nlewis;homework;blahblahblah;12/12/12", "\n", ";");
```